# How yeoman install somePackage works?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, yeoman

When I run `yeoman install handlebars` I get the following output:

```
Running "bower:install:handlebars" (bower) task
bower cloning git://github.com/components/handlebars.js
bower cached git://github.com/components/handlebars.js
bower fetching handlebars
```

It doesn't copy handlebars to the current project's plugins or vendors directory. It exits without an error message. Is this the right behaviour?

To me it seemed like a bug so I've created an [issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/542) on yeoman's github page. But I'm not sure.

Comment: same problem here with ember-data.  Did you get a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue here's what I did. I realized yeoman did not install bower for me and it depends on bower for installing libraries. So, to resolve this issue - install bower manually like this: `npm install bower -g`